# owlapi HERMIT and SPARQL

Tags: java, sparql, owl-api

How is it possible to execute a SPARQL Query in Java using the HERMIT reasoner 1.3.8? I'm using owlapi 4.2 and i have loaded the HERMIT reasoner using:

```
OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory();
OWLReasoner reasonerHermit = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(ontology);
```

Unfortunately i could not find any explanation how to execute a SPARQL Query with this reasoner?! Is this possible at all? If not, what other possibilities (other reasoners) do i have using owlapi and SPARQL?

**EDIT:**

I now know that i need a SPARQL Engine. This is why i used SPARQL-DL like this:

```
QueryEngine engine = QueryEngine.create(manager, reasoner, true);
Query query = Query.create("...");
QueryResult result = engine.execute(query);
System.out.println(result);
```

The query works, but if I'm now getting something like

```
?de.derivo.sparqldlapi.Var@69 = http://www.example.com/project1#document_1
```

how do i get out the `http://www.example.com/project1#document_1`? I could not find a proper Method for getting this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HermiT is an OWL reasoner and not a SPARQL engine. There is an API called SPARQL-DL, but according to its [website](http://www.derivo.de/en/resources/sparql-dl-api/) it supports just OWL API v3.x. A newer forked version with OWL API 4 support can be found as part of the Protege project: https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-dl-api

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source for QueryResult, [available here](https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-dl-api/blob/master/src/main/java/de/derivo/sparqldlapi/QueryResult.java), what you have there is a query binding. You have methods to iterate over all the bindings, and you should find the value you are after in the bound values of the binding.